# Python won't compile to lib64

Tags: installation, python

I'm trying to compile Python (2.6.5) on a 64bit system, using the following options:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64
```

however, `libpython` isn't being installed in `/usr/lib64`, but rather `/usr/lib`. This means when I invoke `python` from the commandline an error is raised.

I know I can hack round the problem by adding a symlink to the .so file in `/usr/lib` but that's not really fixing, nor understanding, the problem.

What do I need to do to get Python to install correctly?

Comment: What distribution is this?  Does it not have a Python 2.6 package?  Does it have older versions of Python packaged?  I'd download the source package and look at their build rules to see how Python is supposed to be build and installed on your particular distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The native `python` package does a *number* of patches to the Python source in order to get it to use `lib64`. I recommend you find the native source package, extract its contents, and apply the patches yourself to the upstream source.

Actually, I recommend you generate your own package for the newer version, but that can be daunting if you've never created a package before.